# How to edit the hole size in this SCAD file

Tags: python, c++, cad, 3d-modelling, openscad

I am very new to 3D modelling (just started today) and I found this amazing code by Iron Momo (link: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:211020 ). I can edit it in OpenSCAD (https://openscad.org/downloads.html)

My only issue is that I need the holes in each row to be a different size, one row of 16mm and the other being 13mm. Is this possible with the code below?

Thank you for any help you can provide in advance!

```
//Customizable test tube rack
//by Iron Momo

// preview[view:north, tilt:top]

/* [Basic] */

//Number of tubes
nb_tubes = 5; //[1:20]
//Number of rows
nb_rows = 1; //[1:10]

//Tubes diameter (mm)
hole_diameter = 16;

//Material thickness (mm)
thickness = 5; //[3,4,5,10]

//Total height (mm)
height1 = 80;
//Middle height (mm)
height2 = 20;


output_type = "STL"; //[DXF,STL]

/* [Hidden] */
inter=10;
width1 = nb_tubes*hole_diameter + (nb_tubes+1)*inter;
width2 = nb_tubes*hole_diameter + (nb_tubes+1)*inter+2*thickness;
depth1= nb_rows*hole_diameter+nb_rows*inter;
depth2= nb_rows*hole_diameter+nb_rows*inter+2*thickness;

if(output_type=="STL")
{linear_extrude(height = thickness, center = false) rack_creation();
}

if(output_type=="DXF")
{rack_creation();}

module rack_creation()
{
bottom();
translate([0,depth2+5,0]) middle();
translate([0,2*depth2+10,0]) top();
translate([0,-height2-15,0])side1();
translate([0,-2*height2-30,0])side1();
translate([-5,-2*height2-30,0])rotate([0,0,90])side2();
translate([-5,height1-2*height2,0])rotate([0,0,90])side2();

}



module bottom()
{
difference()
{
    square([width2,depth2]);
    for (i = [1:nb_tubes])
        {
            translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,0,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);

            translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,depth1+thickness,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);
        }

    translate([0,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([0,3*depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);

    translate([width1+thickness,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([width1+thickness,3*depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
}
}


module top()
{
difference()
{
    square([width2,depth2]);
    for (i=[0:nb_rows-1])
        {
            for (j = [1:nb_tubes])
                {
                    translate([thickness+j*inter+(j-1)*hole_diameter+hole_diameter/2,thickness+inter/2+hole_diameter/2+i*(hole_diameter+inter),0]) circle(hole_diameter/2);
                }
        }

    translate([0,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([0,3*(depth2/5),0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);

    translate([width1+thickness,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([width1+thickness,3*(depth2/5),0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
}
}

module middle()
{
difference()
{
top();
for (i = [1:nb_tubes])
    {
        translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,0,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);

        translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,depth1+thickness,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);
    }
}
}


module side1()
{
difference()
{
    translate([0,thickness,0]) square([width2,height2]);

    translate([0,thickness+height2/3,0]) square([thickness,height2/3]);
    translate([width1+thickness,thickness+height2/3,0]) square([thickness,height2/3]);
}
for (i = [1:nb_tubes])
    {
        translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,0,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);

        translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,height2+thickness,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);
    }
}

module side2()
{
difference() 
{
    //Forme de base
    translate([thickness,0,0]) square([height1,depth2]);

    //Trous middle
    translate([height2+thickness,0,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([height2+thickness,4*depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([height2+thickness,2*depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);

    //Trous side1
    translate([thickness,0,0]) square([height2/3,thickness]);
    translate([thickness,depth1+thickness,0]) square([height2/3,thickness]);
    translate([thickness+2*height2/3,0,0]) square([height2/3,thickness]);
    translate([thickness+2*height2/3,depth1+thickness,0]) square([height2/3,thickness]);


}

//Ajout bottom
translate([0,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
translate([0,3*(depth2/5),0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);


//Ajout top
translate([height1+thickness,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
translate([height1+thickness,3*(depth2/5),0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements with holes are created by the same module, the module top(). In the example the size of the holes is set in the module

```
circle(hole_diameter/2);
```

so every instance of top() has the same hole diameter. To solve this you can invoke the module with parameters, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSCAD_User_Manual/User-Defined_Functions_and_Modules#Modules

```
module top(hd)
{
difference()
{
    square([width2,depth2]);
    for (i=[0:nb_rows-1])
        {
            for (j = [1:nb_tubes])
                {
                translate([thickness+j*inter+(j-1)*hole_diameter+hole_diameter/2,thickness+inter/2+hole_diameter/2+i*(hole_diameter+inter),0]) circle(hd/2);
                }
        }

    translate([0,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([0,3*(depth2/5),0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);

    translate([width1+thickness,depth2/5,0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
    translate([width1+thickness,3*(depth2/5),0]) square([thickness,depth2/5]);
}
}

module middle(hd)
{
difference()
{
top(hd);
for (i = [1:nb_tubes])
    {
        translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,0,0]) square([hole_diameter,thickness]);

        translate([thickness+i*inter+(i-1)*hole_diameter,depth1+thickness,0])       square([hole_diameter,thickness]);
    }
}
}
```

then set another variable:

```
//Tubes diameter (mm)
hole_diameter = 16;    // of the middle element
hole_diameter_1 = 13;  // of the top element
```

and use them when calling the modules top() and middle() in rack_creation():

```
module rack_creation()
{
bottom();
translate([0,depth2+5,0]) middle(hole_diameter);
translate([0,2*depth2+10,0]) top(hole_diameter_1);
…
```